# How to check two conditions are met within an if-else statement combining jQuery and regular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to call up 3 different window alerts depending on specific conditions. Within my if-else statement, I have the following (snippet only):

```
 $('input[name=answer]').on('change', function() {

            if ((practice_trials.stimulus == "images/some-bias1.png" || practice_trials.stimulus == "images/some-unbias1.png" || practice_trials.stimulus == "images/all-unbias3.png") && $('input[id=no]:radio').is(':checked')){
                window.alert("Oops, you should have taken the box!");
            } else if (practice_trials.stimulus == 'images/all-false3.png' && $('input[id=yes]:radio').is(':checked')){
                window.alert("Oops, you should have left the box behind!");
            } else {
                window.alert("You've got it right!"); 
            }
```

The jQuery is pointing to a radio button selection, while the JS is referring to a dictionary stored in a separate file called *practice_trials.js*. The dictionary has the following structure:

```
var practice_trials = [
{question: "Should you bring Johnny this box or not?",
 QUD: "Johnny says: 'I want you to bring me the box where ...",
 sentence: "some | of the | black marbles | are | inside | the case.'",
 option1: "Bring it", 
 option2: "Leave it", 
 stimulus: "images/some-bias1.png",
 helpText: "Press the SPACE bar to reveal the words"},
```

The HTML has the following structure:

```
<p class="answer-container nodisplay">
            <label for="yes" class="button-answer">{{option1}}</label>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" id="yes"
                value={{option1}} />
            <input type="radio" name="answer" id="no" value={{option2}} />
            <label for="no" class="button-answer">{{option2}}</label>
</p>
```

So far, regardless of the conditions, I always get the last alert ("You've got it right!").

Comment: I will suggest you use console.log to check all the values at runtime before the evaluation takes place and see if your if-else statements are on point. There are elements in your code that we cannot evaluate unless we see runtime values.

Comment: There is no `practice_trials.stimulus`.

Comment: @misorude Isn't _stimulus_ a key in the _practice_trials_ dictionary?

Comment: No – because `practice_trials` is an _array_. That array contains one single item, which itself in turn is an object with specific keys. So, `practice_trials[0].stimulus`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read how to [ask], especially how to create a [mcve]

Comment: @Ph0b0x Thanks for your suggestion. Where exactly should the console.log go? Do you mean something like `$('input[name=answer]').on('change', function() {
            console.log('input[name=answer] was changed')
            if ((practice_trials.stimulus ...`

Comment: @misorude Thanks a lot. I've made the changes and it solved my problem!

Comment: I agree with @Tien suggestion about using an onclick event to handle this. you can use the console log on: console.log(practice_trials.stimulus) right before the IF-ELSE. Although i also agree that it seems to not be defined.

Comment: @Ph0b0x I still get mixed up with the basic data structures sometimes. The code itself was working, what was wrong is exactly that something was not properly defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data is an array. Are using handlebar (or something similar) to loop through your dictionary? If so, where are you putting your if/else statement?

Assuming that your data is correctly looped, here is an example of it working for that 1 specific dataset you have provided.

The trick here is primarily on the .on('click') function: http://jsfiddle.net/ujpz9sny/
`$("input[type='radio']").on('click', function(e) {
  // # you'd want your if/else statement here to check for correct answer
})`

There are better ways of doing this as well using `form` if you are not absolutely set on doing it like this.

Comment: For what it's worth: I've tried your version of the code and it works too! Should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: If you are referring to using `form`, then there is no difference from what I can tell. It's just about how easy it is for you to read and know exactly what it does for future references.

Comment: I meant using `$("input[type='radio']").on('click', function(e) {}` as opposed to `$('input[name=answer]').on('change', function(){}`.

Comment: If you're planning on using .on('change') then it should work as well in this format.
    `$("input[name='answer']").on('change', function(e) {})`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad you fixed it @VMacuchS